# SharePoint how to run javascript file only in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to run a script file only in edit mode in SharePoint? (all pagelayouts)

I want to but a click event on a sharepoint ribbon button to display / hide some elements on the particular site.

If yes, please make an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<PublishingWebConrols:EditModePanel ID="test" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Edit">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/js/test.js %>/>" ></script>' 
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```